# Adding JARs to use sql UDF in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-zeppelin

I want to use custom UDF which are defined in my libaray. I have used the following code for that:

```
%spark2
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.year

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql(s"ADD JAR /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/myLib.jar")

val df = sqlContext.sql("select parse_datetime(start_timestamp, 'CET', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS') AS TIMESTAMP) from temp)
```

The above code complains about missing function "`parse_datetime`", so apparently, ADD JAR statement is not adding myLib. Is there a syntax problem or what is that I am missing. I am running this in Zeppelin.

I have also copied the myLib.jar in `$SPARK_HOME/lib` folder but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have given the exact path of myLib.jar in the dependencies section of spark intertreper. It works now.

Comment: How you have added jar to spark interpreter? Do you mean, adding jar in pom.xml or build.sbt file?

Comment: This was specific to Zeppelin. There one can add customer jars in the dependencies section of spark intertreper in Zepplin. What is that you are trying to do?